# AngularJS make a simple group by

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, group-by

I have trouble with a group by in AngularJS.
This is my code:

```
 <div class="ibox float-e-margins collapsed">
     <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in costList | groupBy: 'Month'">
            {{group}}
          <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="costList in value">

             </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

When I put `| groupBy: 'Month'` in the code it shows an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/unpr?p0=groupByFilterProvider%20%3C-%20groupByFilter
at angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:14
at angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:53
at Object.d [as get] (angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:50)
at angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:53
at Object.d [as get] (angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:50)
at angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:173
at V (angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:134)
at angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:132
at p (angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:15)
at V (angularjs?v=3IGOL90Rnusy-QTWOoBPXNF6utfbZEM46kAny3Khxb81:132) "<!-- ngRepeat: (key, value) in costList | groupBy: '[Month]' -->"
```

I assume that I'm missing some dependencies, but I don't know which file I am missing.

The js file is as follows,

```
var app = angular.module('BusinessTripBudget', ['angular.filter']);
   app.controller('Budget', ["$scope", "$http", "$window", "$compile", "$q", 
     function ($scope, $http, $window, $compile, $q) {

        //Here I put the code that retrieves data

   }]);
```

I'm using  AngularJS v1.6.6

this is my script order:

```
            jquery-ui.min.js
            angular.min.js
            MyCustomJS.js
```

Comment: Are you able to use any other filter ? If not, remember to import angular-filter.js in your index.html page.

Comment: show your `<script>` order

Comment: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter module is missing

Comment: please provide costList  object

Comment: Naga Sai A thanks. I added the file and now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @pasluc74669, if resolved you can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error shows that the angular-filter module is missing

Please follow below steps
Include angular-filter.js (or angular-filter.min.js) in your index.html, after including Angular itself.

Add 'angular.filter' to your main module's list of dependencies.

Follow steps to add dependencies from https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter